# Mouseover working on whole page instead of one element?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, mouseover

I'm a beginner with web-programming and unfortunately I already have a problem. I want to use the mouseover (mouseout) function of prototype to add or remove a class, but for some reason the alerts (for debugging) show up at the very first load of the page. I know this must be something ridiculous to ask, but I can't see the problem. I want the alerts to come only when I go over the object with the class "menu".

This is my code:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var menuitems = $$('.menu');
    for(var i = 0;i < menuitems.length;i++){
        menuitems[i].observe("mouseover",alert("over"));
        menuitems[i].observe("mouseout",alert("out"));
    }
}
```

PS. I did a search on google and stackoverflow but couldn't find a similar question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "unfortunately I already have a problem". Welcome to the wonderful world of programming!

Comment: thx, I'm looking forward to more problems :)

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd argument to the `observe` method should be a *function* - by actually calling `alert()` there, you're just raising an alert when the event handler is *defined* (i.e. when the page loads), not when it is triggered.

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var menuitems = $$('.menu');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
        menuitems[i].observe("mouseover", function() {
            alert("over");
        });
        menuitems[i].observe("mouseout", function() {
            alert("out");
        });
    }
};
```

There I've defined event handler functions inline, but haven't called them. They'll be called when the mouseover/mouseout event is fired. Alternatively, you could define the functions in advance:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var handleMouseover = function() {
        alert("over");
    };
    var handleMouseover = function() {
        alert("out");
    };

    var menuitems = $$('.menu');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
        menuitems[i].observe("mouseover", handleMouseover);
        menuitems[i].observe("mouseout", handleMouseout);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Stu, you just solved the problem for me :D Do you also know how to pass parameters to a function which is defined through a var?? *curious* :)